# underscore.js: Access element from template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, underscore.js

I'm using the underscore.js template function _.template(). I have code like this:

```
$('#content').append(_.template(superTemplate));
$('#elementFromTemplate').doFancyStuff();
```

Now I want to access an element via jQuery which is in rendered in the template. But since this is happen async it is not available to this moment. Is there any way to wait for finish rendering the template?

Comment: jQuery's append function works synchronously. What exactly is the error you're receiving?

Comment: No error but the jquery selector does not return the element.

Comment: Oh no! I'm such a fool. I stored the $('#elementFromTemplate') in a variable **before** I append the template. What is the right way to handle this dump question? Delete or keep it?

Comment: I think you also have another issue that the thing you're trying to `append` is  a function returned by `template` rather than the actual HTML. See my answer below.

Comment: As an aside, if you wanted to be a little more functional (since you're using underscore), you can see that appending content is the composition of compiling a template and appending it. This can be made into a composed function that works easily for all templates: http://jsfiddle.net/b2hyje7k/

Comment: and also, if your template is only HTML, why use `_.template` at all? Just pass the HTML string to `append`.

Comment: It is just pure HTML to have it simple for the example. And furthermore I don't want to have HTML data in my JS files (if they are a larger than one line).
Your advise with the composed function is really interesting. Thank you.